# can react js components and laravel blade work in one single project? if not, what's the best approach?

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, laravel-5

I have a project that is fully developed in laravel mvc design pattern, and now i want to change few of the blade files to react js components within the same project directory. what would be the best way to do that?
so that whenever user views those pages, they should be appeared from react component, also i need to manage session stuff on these react components as well like logged-in user details etc...

Comment: First thing you need to do is to slow down to the level of one question at a time. Than when you separate issues, start to solve that first one. After eventual fail, you should post here (in question, not in comment) code of your trial, error you get and expectation. Google for "perfect question by Jon Skeet" to see how you should do this all with greatest chance to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use react js in laravel and for that you need to convert your blade file into react js view component.
For more details please see below url for sample how to use react js component into laravel directory.
https://dev.to/lvtdeveloper/using-react-in-a-laravel-application-8fp